# How to deploy Asp.net core 2.2 application on heroku using docker image and avoid Dockerfile errors

Tags: docker, heroku, asp.net-core, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm building an asp.net core 2.2 application in docker image to host it in Heroku, but i don't know what's the exact dockerfile configuration should be, i used an example of Dockerfile but i get this error after opening the application on heroku:

### Application error: An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command heroku logs --tail

This is the log file :

`2019-04-10T02:51:45.024996+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-04-10T02:51:52.077699+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command /bin/sh -c ASPNETCORE_URLS\=http://\*:\58395\ dotnet\ sitehidamek.dll
2019-04-10T02:51:53.841749+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-04-10T02:51:53.820061+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 145
2019-04-10T02:51:53.715427+00:00 app[web.1]: Did you mean to run dotnet SDK commands? Please install dotnet SDK from:
2019-04-10T02:51:53.715458+00:00 app[web.1]: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409
2019-04-10T03:34:20.255335+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-04-10T03:34:26.731799+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command /bin/sh -c ASPNETCORE_URLS\=http://\*:\41495\ dotnet\ sitehidamek.dll
2019-04-10T03:34:28.273366+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-04-10T03:34:28.245573+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 145
2019-04-10T03:34:28.208525+00:00 app[web.1]: Did you mean to run dotnet SDK commands? Please install dotnet SDK from:
2019-04-10T03:34:28.208542+00:00 app[web.1]: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409
2019-04-10T04:57:22.211933+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-04-10T04:57:28.788242+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command /bin/sh -c ASPNETCORE_URLS\=http://\*:\5818\ dotnet\ sitehidamek.dll
2019-04-10T04:57:30.339475+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-04-10T04:57:30.315137+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 145
2019-04-10T04:57:30.260093+00:00 app[web.1]: Did you mean to run dotnet SDK commands? Please install dotnet SDK from:
2019-04-10T04:57:30.260116+00:00 app[web.1]: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409
2019-04-10T07:38:35.071679+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-04-10T07:38:42.362172+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command /bin/sh -c ASPNETCORE_URLS\=http://\*:\30695\ dotnet\ sitehidamek.dll
2019-04-10T07:38:43.942597+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-04-10T07:38:43.928214+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 145
2019-04-10T07:38:43.874881+00:00 app[web.1]: Did you mean to run dotnet SDK commands? Please install dotnet SDK from:
2019-04-10T07:38:43.874911+00:00 app[web.1]: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409
2019-04-10T12:01:49.430309+00:00 app[api]: Deployed web (a1ffce692888) by user javator.developper@gmail.com
2019-04-10T12:01:53.388766+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-04-10T12:01:49.430309+00:00 app[api]: Release v9 created by user javator.developper@gmail.com
2019-04-10T12:01:59.449423+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command /bin/sh -c ASPNETCORE_URLS\=http://\*:\29461\ dotnet\ sitehidamek.dll
2019-04-10T12:02:02.125769+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-04-10T12:02:02.200130+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-04-10T12:02:02.100437+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 145
2019-04-10T12:02:02.027670+00:00 app[web.1]: Did you mean to run dotnet SDK commands? Please install dotnet SDK from:
2019-04-10T12:02:02.027705+00:00 app[web.1]: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409
2019-04-10T12:02:06.637725+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command /bin/sh -c ASPNETCORE_URLS\=http://\*:\26871\ dotnet\ sitehidamek.dll
2019-04-10T12:02:08.966532+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-04-10T12:02:08.947251+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 145
2019-04-10T12:02:08.904559+00:00 app[web.1]: Did you mean to run dotnet SDK commands? Please install dotnet SDK from:
2019-04-10T12:02:08.904574+00:00 app[web.1]: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409`

Dockerfile content is:

**FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0**

**WORKDIR /app**

**COPY . .**

**CMD ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:$PORT dotnet sitehidamek.dll**

Any suggestions please ?

I'm working on Visual Studio code (Mac os).

Comment: I'm not super familiar with .NET Core. What is `CMD ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:$PORT dotnet sitehidamek.dll` supposed to do?

Comment: Your `Dockerfile` isn't entirely clear. You've made each line bold, which I'm pretty sure isn't actually in your file, but there's no way to know for sure. Please [edit] your question and fix it by pasting your `Dockerfile` into your question, then selecting it and clicking the `{}` button or pressing Ctrl+K to format it as code. Don't add any additional formatting to that section; it should _exactly_ reflect what you're using.

Comment: Has you shared the full dockerfile content? If true, it is total wrong, try to follow [Dockerize a .NET Core application](https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/dotnetcore/)